# access real time database within onAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to access firebase database after creating a user using Auth without any success.
After creating the user with Auth I'd like to save it on realtime database and add more fields.

```
signUpBrother(email: string, password: string) {
  this.fireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

  this.fireAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    this.firebase.list('brothers').set(uid, {
      'email': user.email,
      'nickname': 'nickname',
      'avatar': 'avatar',
      'is_big_brother': true
    })
  })
}
```

the error I'm getting is:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'firebase' of undefined

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `this` inside onAuthStateChanged is not the same object as you expect. Do something like `var _this = this;` before onAuthStateChanged and then use the variable inside the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As codtex commented `this` has a different meaning in the callback than outside of it. And the new `this` doesn't have a `firebase` property.

To make sure you can access your function, you can capture `this` under a different name:

```
signUpBrother(email: string, password: string) {
  this.fireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

  var that = this;    
  this.fireAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    that.firebase.list('brothers').set(uid, {
      'email': user.email,
      'nickname': 'nickname',
      'avatar': 'avatar',
      'is_big_brother': true
    })
  })
}
```